# How do You average times the best two times in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas, array-formulas

We need to take a results list of three times in the following format (mm:ss.sss) and figure out the fastest 2 times are and then average them.

All assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this formula

`=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A3,{1,2}))`

That assumes you have three cells in one range, like A1:A3 - but SMALL also allows you to look at 3 separate cells if required, e.g. A1, A3 and A5, like this:

`=AVERAGE(SMALL((A1,A3,A5),{1,2}))`

Comment: I had no clue you could do that with the `Small` function... That's an awesome thing to know!! +1!

Answer (score 2):

Assume your data set is in cells A1-A3, you could do something like:

```
=(SMALL($A$1:$A$3,1)+SMALL($A$1:$A$3,2))/2
```

That'll take the 2 fastest times and give you their average - This also allows for you to inclrease the number of times to more than 3 and it will still give you the average of the 2 fastest.